# Converting multi valued column into json column in spark scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Below is one of the string columns from my dataframe. It is a multi valued column. I want to convert this multi valued column into a json column.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+                                         
|                     Vision                              |           
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|   Version_New:E=true,HDR:E=true,DolVision:E=true,       |                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am using the below code to convert this column into json column.

```
val df2 = df1.select(to_json(struct($"Vision")) as "Vision")
```

Below is the output I am getting.

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+                                
|                     Vision                                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"Vision":" Version_New:E=true, HDR:E=true, DolyVision:E=true,}  |                                                                  
|                                                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Likewise, I have many such multi-valued columns in my dataframe, I want to convert all these multivalued columns into json columns. Could someone please let me know if there is a way to achieve this instead of manually converting each column into json.

EDIT:
I tried the below to extract a column from the json.

```
val testdf = df1.select(df1.columns.map(c => to_json(struct(col(c))).as(c)): _*)
display(test.select(col("Vision.HDR:E")))
```

I am getting the below error.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from Vision#2190: need struct type but got string;
```

In this case,should we cast the datatype to struct.

Comment: You can use `df1.select(df.columns.map(c => to_json(struct(col(c))).as(c)): _*)` you can replace df.columns with list of columns that you want to use

Comment: @koiralo my list of columns will change periodically based on sources,and there are few columns which are not multivalued. so, is there any way to change the the multivalued columns to json as in when the source schema changes.

Comment: create a list of columns that are not multivalued and except those use the columns to convert to  json

Comment: @koiralo I followed the approach, but unable to select the json columns. Im getting the below error. org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from Vision#2190: need struct type but got string;